# Are the temperatures that I'm seeing normal?

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, temperature

I bought a new mid-2014 15" Macbook Pro, and noticed some interesting temperatures in iStats. The idle temperature seems to be around 50 degrees celcius with an ambient temperature of approximately 30 degrees. However, whenever I play games, particularly DOTA 2 in Bootcamp, the temperature shoots up and sustains at around 90 degrees celcius throughout the whole gaming session. Is this normal? Or do I have a defective Macbook?

I guess a question I should also be asking is how much will the life of my MacBook be lowered after constant gaming (i.e. ~10 hours/week of cpu temps at 90 degrees celsius)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the search function of this site or Google to find very very similar questions.